# git get conflicts from past merge without running merge once again

Tags: git, merge

I've merged two branches. Got lot's of conflicts. Resolved them all. Now I'm not sure, maybe I've made an error during conflict resolution. And I don't see no another way to check is it  true — just run merge again, and check conflicts one by one.

This means I need to create one more branch to store results of my merge, right?

Can I avoid it? Maybe it's possible to get all conflicting files with all these `<<<<<<`, `======`, `>>>>>>` from somewhere in git, without running merge once again?

Comment: Maybe you should accept one of the answers.

Comment: I don't think the answers actually do answer the question.  Subsequent merges shouldn't show the same conflicts from previous merges.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to look at what the merge did you can do

```
git show <hash-of-merge-commit>
```

If you want to redo the entire merge you do

```
git checkout <branch-that-you-merged-to>
git reset --hard <hash-of-the-commit-just-before-the-merge>
git merge <branch-that-you-merged-in>
```

If you want to redo the merge and then compare the second merge to the first merge (to consider if it was better) you can do:

```
git checkout <branch-that-you-merged-to>
git rev-parse HEAD
```

This gives you the hash of the current commit. Note it down. Then do

```
git reset --hard <hash-of-the-commit-just-before-the-merge>
git merge <branch-that-you-merged-in>
```

Finish the merge, then do this to compare the merges

```
git difftool <hash-of-commit-noted-above>
```

If you felt that the original merge was better, you can do

```
git reset --hard <hash-of-commit-noted-above>
```

Comment: During the merge, you can play around with "git show :1:file.txt" to get to the merge-base, ":2:file.txt" to show the merge target file, ":3:file.txt" to show the merging-in file

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is trivial. First of all, you need find sha1 id of the merge commit using `git log`. When you do the next:

```
git checkout <sha1>^1
git merge <sha1>^2
```

you will be in a headless state. `^n` means n-th parent of a commit. So, no branches are created. You could resolve conflicts again more carefully and then

```
git diff HEAD..<sha1>
```

to see if there are any differences in the conflict resolutions.

BTW, branch in a git just a human-friendly name for a sha1 of a commit, so don't afraid to create them as much as you wish.

PS: If you work in Windows, `^` symbol in command line is special, you need to double it or quote command line arguments.