# Getting a list of all historical merge conflicts in Git

Tags: git

I'd like to get a list of all historical merge conflicts in git.

The purpose is to identify the areas in our code base that are most frequently conflicted, and then look for the root cause of the conflicts.

Perhaps conflicts are caused by design issues (code not using the single responsibility or open closed principles), or perhaps merge conflicts are caused by poor work allocation or sequencing, or perhaps they happen for other reasons.

Either way, they slow developers down, and potentially introduce new defects into our code base when the merge goes bad. I'd like to know where they're happening so I can try and reduce them, and then measure the reduction over time.

Any ideas on how to mine git successfully to obtain historical merge conflict information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git get conflicts from past merge without running merge once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048094/git-get-conflicts-from-past-merge-without-running-merge-once-again), but maybe you want a different approach.

Comment: in case of conflicts resolved in the merge itself, the merge commit contains modifications on code (which other merge don't have). Thus you could look for merges that have code modifications. If the conflict was resolved by a rebase, I don't think you will be able to find them once rebased and merged/fast-forwarded.

Comment: Are you looking for conflicts that occurred during operations that use merging (such as rebase, cherry-pick, and revert) but do not make merge *commits*? Or are you looking for conflicts that occurred during a `git merge` operation that left behind a merge commit?

Comment: @OznOg I am only interested in conflicts where auto-merge has failed and a person has had to get involved to merge a branch they're working on into master (or master into their branch). I think the approach you're describing is workable in theory?

Comment: @torek I think the later, but only conflicts that were not auto-merged, and a person needed to get involved.

Comment: OK, in this case it's possible to automate it, using what OznOg suggested. Essentially, you have Git *re-perform* each merge. You check out, as a detached HEAD, the first parent of each merge, then run `git merge <hash>` where `<hash>` is the second parent of each merge. If the merge succeeds, this merge was done automatically. If it fails, the merge had to be done "by hand": use `git merge --abort` to abandon the effort-so-far. In any case, move on to the next merge to test. This has one minor flaw: merge commits don't record their `-s` strategy, nor any options. If those affected [continued]

Comment: ... If those affected the merge result in some way, your re-merge or attempted re-merge won't know that and may get a different success or failure result. In any case, to find the merges, use `git log --merges` or `git rev-list --merges` (`--merges` is a synonym for `--min-parents=2`). Start from whichever branch tip(s) you're interested in; use `--branches` to start from all branch tips; use `--all` to start from all references.